# Probability two people born on $1$ April

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Find the smallest number of people you need to choose
at random so that the probability that at least two of them
were both born on April $1$ exceeds $1/2$.

My answer:

Total of *n* people chosen at random

Event E -> At least $2$ people among the *n* people have birthday on April $1$

Event E' -> Only $1$ person has birthday on April 1 and $n-1$ people do NOT have birth day on April $1$

The probability for a person to have birthday on April 1 = $\frac{1}{365}$

The probability for a person to NOT have birthday on April 1 = $\frac{364}{365}$

$P(E)=1-P(E') = 1-((\frac{364}{365})^{n-1}) > \frac{1}{2}$

Solving the inequality gives the smallest $n = 254$

However, Book answer is $614$.

How ? Can someone please explain?

Comment: You forgot about the event "no person has a birthday on april 1."

Comment: You forgot loads of details! Binomial coefficients?! I get the result 613, however ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us add the event $E''$ of no person having a birthday on April 1, like suggested by 5xum. Then
$$
\begin{align}
P(E')&=\frac{1}{365}\cdot\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{n-1}\cdot\binom{n}{1}\\
&=\frac{364^{n-1}}{365^n}\cdot n\\
&\text{ }\\
&\text{ }\\
P(E'')&=\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{n}\cdot\binom{n}{0}\\
&=\frac{364^n}{365^n}
\end{align}
$$
And when you then solve $P(E)=1-P(E')-P(E'')=1/2$ you get $n\approx 612.257$ so for $n\geq 613$ you get the desired inequality. [Link to solution using Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-364%5E%28n-1%29%2F365%5En*n-364%5En%2F365%5En%3D1%2F2).

Comment: Doing this for a leap year gives the book answer, 614